# How to automatically masking data

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in C++. I had a problem masking data automatically from the program. The program should auto-select the data that want to mask. Right now, my program only can choose manually which data need to mask by inserting the input. I've tried to figure it out but I cannot solve it. Below is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

const int ROW = 7;
const int COL = 7;


string raw[ROW][COL] = {{"Customer ID", "Name", "Premise", "Street No.", "Town", "Meter No.", "Usage (kWh)"},
             {"112", "mike", "87", "Jln 12", "port", "24564532", "466"},
             {"545", "danny", "25", "Jln 24", "casa", "82251928", "578"},
             {"323", "tan", "34", "Jln 36", "cattleya", "12193729", "253"},
             {"843", "jess", "86", "Jln 48", "mount", "98829101", "316"},
             {"218", "jack", "44", "Jln 11", "river", "1927192", "212"},
             {"298", "bob", "99", "Jln 60", "stall", "53328789", "266"}};

void loadData(vector<vector<string> > &data)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        vector<string> thisrow;
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
            thisrow.push_back(raw[i][j]);
        }
        data.push_back(thisrow);
    }
}

void printData(vector<vector<string> > data)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[i].size(); j++) {
            cout << setw(8) << left << data[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void swapCol(vector<vector<string> > &data, const int colno, const int x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        int s = (rand() % (data.size()-1)) + 1;
        int r = (rand() % (data.size()-1)) + 1;

        // Swap premise number
        string temp = data[s][colno];
        data[s][colno] = data[r][colno];
        data[r][colno] = temp;
    }
}

void maskCol(vector<vector<string> > &data, const int colno)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < data.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[i][colno].length(); j++) {
            if (j != 0) {
                if (data[i][colno][j] >= 'a' && data[i][colno][j] <= 'z') data[i][colno][j] = 'z';
                else if (data[i][colno][j] >= 'A' && data[i][colno][j] <= 'Z') data[i][colno][j] = 'Z';
                else if (data[i][colno][j] >= '0' && data[i][colno][j] <= '9') data[i][colno][j] = '9';
            }
        }
    }
}
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(0));
    vector<vector<string> > data;
    int operation, input;
    string cust;

    // Insert data into vector
    loadData(data);

    while (true) {

        cout << "Current data:\n";
        printData(data);

        cout << "Available Events:\n";
        cout << "1. Energy Consumption\n";
        cout << "2. Theft Detection\n";
        cout << "\nChoose an event: ";
        cin >> operation;

        if(operation < 2)
        {
            cout << "\nTelco Provider want to know electric consumption.\n";

            switch (operation) {
            case 1:
                cout << "\nWhich attribute to be swapped?\n";
                cout << "\n1. Customer ID\n";
                cout << "2. Customer name\n";
                cout << "3. Premise number\n";
                cout << "4. Street number\n";
                cout << "5. Town\n";
                cout << "6. Meter number\n";
                cout << "7. Power usage\n";
                cout << "\nYour input: ";
                cin >> input;

                swapCol(data, input-1, data.size()/2);

            break;}
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "\nCST want to identify energy consumption for investigation purpose on electric theft.\n";

        switch (operation){
        case 2:
                cout << "Which attribute to be masked?\n";
                cout << "1. Customer ID\n";
                cout << "2. Customer name\n";
                cout << "3. Premise number\n";
                cout << "4. Street number\n";
                cout << "5. Town\n";
                cout << "6. Meter number\n";
                cout << "\nYour input: ";
                cin >> input;

                maskCol(data, input-1);

            break;

            case 3:
                data.clear();
                loadData(data);
            break;

            default:
                cout << "Invalid operation. Please try again.\n\n";
        }


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Consider using a vector of a class instead. Since you'd know what data you were storing in the class you should also know which parts of the data you'd want to mask when displayed.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Let say, user, choose energy consumption. From energy consumption, the data that I want to mask is customer id, customer name and premise number. Other than that no need to masking. How supposed I need to write the code? I know the swap and mask function already there. But, I'm struggled to implement it.